# Toggle tr when i click on specif element inside td

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this code in jquery, and inside the td I have a div called arrow when I click him I want to toggle the next tr. But this div is inside the td. I tried to use nextUntil, but he works only when I click in the whole TR, I want that work when I only click on arrow div.

```
        $('div.arrow').click(function(){
          $(this).nextUntil('tr.line-addendum').css('display', function(i,v){
            return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
          });
        });

        <tr class="line-validity">  
          <td class="field" nowrap> 
            <div class="arrow">
              <img src="/WebSoc/imagens/setaAudio.gif" alt="Associa" border="0">
            </div>
          </td>   
        </tr>
       <tr class="line-addendum"></tr>
```

So, when I click in the div arrow, I want to toggle the TR line-addendum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the next row from a td use:

```
 var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
```

to get the containing `tr`, then you can use `tr.next()` or equivalent.

Note that `.nextUntil` will get all the rows *until* the matching row (excluding the matching row).  To toggle the addendum rather than rows between, you can use:

```
tr.nextAll(".line-addendum").first()
```

to get the matching addendum.  (this may not match your exact requirements, so could be expanded upon in the question)

Giving (whilst keeping as much of your original code):

```js
$('div.arrow').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .closest("tr")
    .nextAll('tr.line-addendum')
    .first()
    .css('display', function(i, v) {
      return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="line-validity">
  <td class="field" nowrap>
    <div class="arrow">
     Associa
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="line-addendum" style='display:none'>
  <td>addendum</td>
</tr>
</table>
```